# Prism, mapping region to a view

Tags: prism

I'm quite new to Prism. I'm studying QuickStarts shipped with it as well as other examples on the net. Almost all of them make modules aware of what region their view(s) get dropped into. Typically, the method Initalize of a module has a line like the the following.

```
RegionManager.Regions["LeftRegion"].Add(fundView);
```

I feel quite uncomfortable with that. There's a [similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408235/prism-mef-how-to-registerviewwithregion-without-hard-coding-the-region-name) but I think that it should be the responsibility of the shell component to define such mapping. However, I cannot find any example of such approach and I'm not sure whether the bootstrapper is the right place to put such mapping in.

Is this approach completely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is completely wrong. But it makes no sense to have the shell/bootstrapper (that by design doesn't know anything about the application it will host) knows what view goes into which region.

Consider an application that can be extended by simply adding modules into a given folder. When you follow the approach that the module knows where it's views want to reside (the mapping is done in `Initialize()`), this is no problem. I designed my first Prism application that way.

But if your mapping is done in your shell you always have to update your shell (which is part of the base application, not any module) when you want to add another module. This runs contrary to the loosely coupling paradigm. Besides that you have to create one base application for every module constellation. And there are (2^number of modules) permutations you have to cover. That results in loosing your flexibility you gained by using Prism.